Is it correct to add two receptacles next to an electrical box?
I'm a first time homeowner and I need to add a few outlets in my garage for a sprinkler control panel and power tools (table saw, miter saw, shop vac).
At this moment, I'm thinking about adding two GFCI receptacles (it has to be per code, right?) next to the electrical box.
I'm going to run a 12 AWG and add a single 20A circuit breaker.
I'd need to drill the stud and somehow make a hole in the electrical box.
Is it okay if I do this?


what concern do you have?

You don't need two GFCI outlets. The GFCI outlet should be connected to the breaker by its line connection. Its load connection goes to the other outlet, and protects it as well.

I believe OPs question is about drilling a hole in the side of the panel.  Zooming the picture it seems there might be holes with blanks there already.

Please revise to ask a more specific question. See [ask] and take the [tour] for tips.

Your proposal of two GFCI receptacles is not necessary if the second is fed by the first, but if GFCI's are fed that way one fault shuts it all down, and GFCI's are known to fail. So if you feel redundancy is worth a few bucks then two line fed protected receptacles is still a good option.

@crip659 I believe you're right—it looks like there are already knockouts in the side of the panel.  Do you figure it's OK to use the lowest knockout without a bushing?  A bushing the size of the knockout looks like it would require too big a penetration in the stud, but if you can use a 2" knockout but only have to drill a 1" hole in the stud...maybe?

@Huesmann  I believe you need a bushing, cannot just have the wire/cable on the sharp hole.  Jay613's answer seems to be better/easier.

@crip659 I guess what I'm asking is, "does the wood stud constitute a sharp hole?" because the stud penetration would be much smaller than the knockout.

@Huesmann You always need a bushing on metal box knockouts.

@nobody so if you're using that knockout you have to hog out the stud to match?


At this moment, I'm thinking about adding two GFCI receptacles (it has to be per code, right?) next to the electrical box.

You can have share the GFCI feature from one outlet to the next.

I'm going to run a 12 AWG and add a single 20A circuit breaker.

sounds good.

I'd need to drill the stud and somehow make a hole in the electrical box.

drilling boxes is allowed. but often they have break-out holes conveniently located, which means you're not producing metal fragments inside the box.
when  you drill the studs drill in the middle of the stud, because if your hole is near the surface you need to put a metal plate to protect the wires, and that means you'll need to make holes in the drywall.
you will need to use a connector (cable clamp) where the romex enters the box, the nut for this may be tricky to install, but a skinny wrench will probably get you there.
This bit looks wrong, those cables should be clamped, and the opening is too large. this can probably be fixed by using approved connectors and adding a sheet metal cover over the hole.


First the GFCI part:
GFCI can be provided by GFCI/breaker, GFCI/receptacle or GFCI/deadfront (a GFCI device in the form factor of a standard duplex receptacle, but without any receptacles). In each case, the device can provide protection to all devices after the GFCI. In this particular setup, the logical configurations are either:

GFCI/receptacle + ordinary receptacle - this is generally the least expensive method
GFCI/breaker + 2 x ordinary receptacle - this is not such a great idea (aside from cost) when receptacles are in another room because when there is a GFCI trip you have to go to the breaker panel to reset. But the panel is right here so it could work just fine.

The tricky part is the physical installation. If the panel was surface-mounted instead of flush-mounted then it would be easy: remove a knockout, install a conduit nipple and attach the other end to a box with the 2 receptacles. But since it is flush-mounted, you either use conduit and definitely have some drywall work, or you might be able to:

Cut a hole for a large box on the left side of the stud, but only a few inches away in order to...
Drill a hole in the stud using the box hole for access and
Remove a bottom knockout from the panel and
Carefully fish between panel and box hole, threading through the stud

Definitely not a code issue with receptacles in that location, just a question of how to do it with minimal drywall repairs.

I suggest that while you are doing this work, you double the capacity of what you're installing.  You are likely to want more outlets (for example, for recharging bicycle lights, a Bluetooth speaker for music, a work light, etc etc) and to want more than 20 Amps (for example, for running your table  saw and shop vac at the same time).   Install two GFCI outlets on two new 20A circuits, and from each GFCI outlet install at least one more outlet.  You can do all the very easily in two 4x4 metal junction boxes.
There are already holes punched out of the sides of the breaker panel.  It will be hard to use one on the side where it's up against the stud.  And hard to drill your own.  Punch one out on the bottom of the panel, install a strain relief connector in it, and drill through the stud lower than the panel.

It is most certianly correct to add outlets right next to the main panel. That's the first thing I do when installing a panel so I have power and can get rid of the generator or temporary power from the power company.
Do yourself a favor and carefully remove a piece of drywall at the bottom of the panel, 6"x centerline stud to stud. Now you can easily drill through the stud and also access a knockout from the bottom of the panel and add the apporpriate box to cable connector.
As mentioned in the above comments and answers, you'll need GFCI protection on these outlets and you'll have to decide which way to do it.  Then simply replace the drywall section and mud/tape as needed.
